# изменение значение переменной в другом файле

Tags: python, python-3.x, config, value, customtkinter

хочу реализовать изменение переменной в файле cfg.py при изменении значений при работе основного скрипта main.py
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код из файла main.py

```
from customtkinter import *
from tkinter import *
import cfg

class ToolTip(object):
    
    def __init__(self, widget):
        self.widget = widget
        self.tipwindow = None
        self.id = None
        self.x = self.y = 0

    def showtip(self, text):
        "Display text in tooltip window"
        self.text = text
        if self.tipwindow or not self.text:
            return
        x, y, cx, cy = self.widget.bbox("insert")
        x = x + self.widget.winfo_rootx() + 57
        y = y + cy + self.widget.winfo_rooty() +27
        self.tipwindow = tw = Toplevel(self.widget)
        tw.wm_overrideredirect(1)
        tw.wm_geometry("+%d+%d" % (x, y))
        label = Label(tw, text=self.text, justify=LEFT,
                      background="#ffffe0", relief=SOLID, borderwidth=1,
                      font=("tahoma", "8", "normal"))
        label.pack(ipadx=1)

    def hidetip(self):
        tw = self.tipwindow
        self.tipwindow = None
        if tw:
            tw.destroy()
            
def CreateToolTip(widget, text):
    toolTip = ToolTip(widget)
    def enter(event):
        toolTip.showtip(text)
    def leave(event):
        toolTip.hidetip()
    widget.bind('<Enter>', enter)
    widget.bind('<Leave>', leave)

win = CTk()
win.title('ETS_Launcher')
win.geometry('555x145')


def combobox_callback(choice):
    scenarij_zn = str(choice)
    cfg.scenarij_val = scenarij_zn
    
def checkbox_event():
    print("checkbox toggled, current value:", check_var.get())
    
    
scenarij = CTkComboBox(win,
                       values=["При запуске", "При закрытии", "По времени"],
                       command=combobox_callback,
                       width=200)
scenarij.place(x=5, y=5)
scenarij.set("Выбор сценария")
CreateToolTip(scenarij, text = 'Выберите сценарий резервного копирования.\n'
                               '"При запуске" - копирование при запуске игры\n'
                               '"При закрытии" - копирование при закрытии игры\n'
                               '"По времени" - копирование по таймеру (цеклично)\n')


minus = CTkButton(win,
                  text='-',
                  fg_color='royalblue',
                  hover_color='cornflowerblue',
                  width=30)
minus.place(x=215, y=5)

time = CTkEntry(win,
                placeholder_text="5",
                width=40)
time.place(x=250, y=5)

plus = CTkButton(win,
                 text='+',
                 fg_color='royalblue',
                 hover_color='cornflowerblue',
                 width=30)
plus.place(x=295, y=5)



object_copy = CTkComboBox(win,
                       values=["ALL", "Medium", "Low"],
                       command=combobox_callback,
                       width=200)
object_copy.place(x=5, y=40)
object_copy.set("Выбор объектов копирования")
CreateToolTip(object_copy, text = 'Выбор элементов копировния.\n'
                                  '"ALL" - копировать всю папку "Euro Truck Simulator 2"\n'
                                  '"Medium" - всё кроме папки "mod"\n'
                                  '"Low" - копирование только профеля "profiles"\n')


check_var = StringVar(value="on")
save_setting = CTkCheckBox(win,
                           text="Save Settings",
                           command=checkbox_event,
                           variable=check_var,
                           onvalue="on", 
                           offvalue="off")
save_setting.place(x=215, y=42)
CreateToolTip(save_setting, text = 'Сохраняет параметры для следующего запуска')


put_game = CTkEntry(win,
                    placeholder_text="Путь к игре",
                    width=400)
put_game.place(x=5, y=75)
CreateToolTip(put_game, text = 'Укажите путь к исполняемому файлу игры')

put_copy = CTkEntry(win,
                    placeholder_text="Путь для копирования",
                    width=400)
put_copy.place(x=5, y=110)
CreateToolTip(put_copy, text = 'Укажите где будет создаваться резервная копия\n'
                               '(папка "ETS_BackUp" создасться автоматически)')


start_minus = CTkButton(win,
                        text='Запуск ETS2\nбез копирования',
                        fg_color='firebrick',
                        hover_color='red',
                        height=65)
start_minus.place(x=410, y=5)
CreateToolTip(start_minus, text = 'Просто запуск игры, без запуска сценария резервного копирования')

start = CTkButton(win,
                  text='Запуск ETS2',
                  fg_color='green',
                  hover_color='limegreen',
                  height=65)
start.place(x=410, y=75)
CreateToolTip(start, text = 'Запуск игры со сценарием резервного копирования')


win.mainloop()
```

Код из файла cfg.py

```
scenarij_val = '0'
```

Comment: Так это не работает. Имортированное обратно не записывается. Хотите, чтобы в файле что-то поменялось - пишите в сам этот файл. Лучше заведите конфиг в виде `json` файла и просто читайте его и пишите, там кода на пару строчек.

Comment: Вы хотите изменить значение переменной в рамках одной сессии или изменить содержимое файла `cfg.py`?